# How to remove the background color from and animated GIF image?

Tags: adobe-photoshop, background, gif

How to remove or change the background color of an animated GIF image? I would like to remove the background color from the attached image.

[image]

Comment: You can use Unscreen.com to remove backgrounds from any gif/video. 
[Source](https://codegena.com/remove-video-background-online-without-green-screen/)

Answer (score 33):

There is this useful site....

http://www.online-image-editor.com/

1. Click on the tab Advanced
2. Transparency
3. Click on gif image, on the background you want to remove

Comment: better experience / results than I expected, great site

Comment: I just tried ten different sites, and this is still the best one nine years later, unless you want AI-based background removal.

Answer (score 4):

Gifs images basically have some 'n' number of layers , which will produce the animation effect.
Open the .gif file in photoshop , all layers will be displayed in the layers panel.
Select magic wand and click on the white area , the area gets selected and hit delete to remove the white part.
Do that on each layer.

Comment: Is there any way to automate this for multiple layers?

Answer (score -1):

I don't think there is any way to do this. If you open a transparent image from Video Frames To Layers it has white background but it has the frames, but if you just load it normally the transparency is there, but for 1 frame only.

Comment: I'm not sure what you're trying to say here. It doesn't seem like you're offering a solution

Comment: Video frames to layers was needed when Adobe broke CS4, they've since fixed it and that issue is no longer present.