# Rainbow color changing GIF in photoshop?

Tags: adobe-photoshop, color, animation, gif, effects

I want to make a rainbow color changing gif, where I can adjust the speed of the color changing and what color it changes to and etc.

### Basically, *as example*, I want to turn this:

[image]

### Into something like this:

[image]

How could I do this?

Let's say I want to ***keep the helmet with the same color*** too.

And also, how would you attach something to an animation, lets say attach shoes on the animation, thats my second question. So like to make a gif with it.

---

Basically my frame animations have a transparent background at the psd file, the one that I posted had a white background.

[image]

as you see

[image]

when I do all the steps you've told me the GIF gets a rainbow color animation, but the background will also have the rainbow color which I don't want, I just want the blue walking thing as a rainbow color changing thing and not the whole background.

Removing the white background, I don't think that will solve my problem then.

Comment: Answer updated from an animated GIF with white transparent as explained at the firs part .

Answer (score 4, accepted):

For the rainbow animation, your file has 47 frames.

- Create a **New Document**, same size as you animation.
- Add 9 **Solid Color Layers** reproducing the rainbow, each layer with one color
- The top layer should have the same color than the first one and all layers must be visible
  `The first layer it is not used at the animation, it's a guide to create the colors`
- **Group** the layers and apply a **Color Blend** to this group
- Delete the background layer and open the **Timeline Panel**

[image: layers]

- **Timeline Panel**: add a *Frame*
- **Layer Panel**: Hide the top layer

[image: second layer]

- **Timeline Panel**: select both frames and click the **Tween Icon** > **Frames to add** = 5 to get the first part of the rainbow animation from nine total parts.

[image: First Rainbow]

- For the next rainbow parts: select the last *Frame*, add a new *Frame*, hide the top visible layer and selecting the last two Frames, apply Tween with the same parameters.
- For the last Frame make all layers visible
- This is the Rainbow 49 frames animation:

[image: rainbow]

- **Timeline Panel**: select all the *Frames*
- **Timeline Panel** > **Options Menu** > **Copy Frames**

[image: copy frames]

- Go to your original GIF file and select all the animation *Frames*
- **Timeline Panel** > **Options Menu** > **Paste Frames** > **Paste Over Selection**

[image: overselection]

- Delete the last two frames

[image: monster]

- For keeping the helmet at the same color, make a mask to each frame, sorry, no automatic way. The best option is having the same animation but just with the helmet and transparent background, must be the same size, the helmet and the file, copying all the frames and pasting over this rainbow animation. Same with the shoes.
- A GIF file doesn't support interactions. For color changing you must decide what's the layers color when you make the animation. The time for each color,  changing the Frame Delay Time. If you need interaction an animated GIF is not the right decision.

**Edit after the question changing:**

To get the transparent background from a GIF with white background once the animation it's done follow [this answer](https://graphicdesign.stackexchange.com/a/48705/120647) https://graphicdesign.stackexchange.com/a/48705/120647

- From this result, selecting a frame is possible to add a black stroke inside to the layer
- Clicking the right button of the mouse > **Copy Layer Style**
- Select all frames and all layers and clicking the right button of the mouse over a layer > **Paste Layer Style**
- Some frames must be retouched but at list most of the work it is automatically done

[image: transp]

Comment: how did you apply a color blend on all of them?

Comment: Applying Tween from the Timeline Panel, as It is explained in the answer. The third icon from the right.

Comment: ok I've found it, btw what colors did you use, your rainbow frame has a bit more colors at the end than mine. like in hex.

Comment: so you said for the last frame, like you mean frame nr 49 or the last frame, where I will do frames to add

Comment: nope I haven't found out, the color fill thing still doesn't get added.

Comment: When you ask a question about how to transform an animated GIF in Photoshop, it is clear that at list you know how the Timeline Panel works. If not, the question must be different. At the bottom of the Timeline panel there are three icons, from right to left:  Trash Can to delete frames, New Frame and Tween.

Comment: I mean where you said apply color blend aka. this: https://i.imgur.com/fLaIepO.png

Comment: Oh I see, I didn't know what a solid color layer was

Comment: when I paste over, the background also changes color and idk how to remove it, I want to keep the transparent background
how would I do that?

Comment: I don't know how it is made your animation, at the question the animation is over a white background. You must think that in a complex file like an animated gif, every little change you make at the final result means a new question. Instead of asking the solution you think you need,  ask about the whole problem you have and what do you want to get as a result. I think this is the only one way to get a good solution for you and a well done answer for the person who will use their time trying to solve it.

Comment: ok I've posted another answer question below these comments.

Comment: exactly thats why I've said, if I remove the white background, I'll have a problem at the end. The problem is the quality, as you see it has white things around it. The animation that I want to turn it into doesn't have it. Question is, if you can remove that white thing around it without damaging the quality of the original image I can accept it.